# Table Lock SQL Server 2 sessions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, locking, sql-server-2016

i have a doubt about the table locks on sql server.

For example, i have one table:

```
RowN    RowText
----------------
1       Row1
2       Row2
3       Row3
```

In session 1 i need to update the table, specifically the "Row1":

```
begin tran
update table
set RowText = 'Row11'
where RowN = 1
```

But, in session 2 (so another user querying the same table) i would like to see only the records not locked by the update in session 1:

```
select * from table

RowN    RowText
----------------
2       Row2
3       Row3
```

This is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"i have a doubt about the table locks on sql server."* What is it you are doubting here exactly? you don't appear to express any opinions/doubts on how table locking works. I have to ask, but why would you want that kind of behaviour? You could end up with a significant amount of data missing from your `SELECT` statement if there are a lot of `UPDATE` statements being run. This could be an [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ok exactly... this could be difficult...even if i have multiple updates in multiple rows or for all the rows in a table i dont want to lock the read of the table in session 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `READPAST` hint:

```
select  *
from    test with(readpast)
```

It will skip rows that are currently locked.